# How would you run end to end testing with playwright and Github actions with your backend/infrastructure?

Tags: testing, automation, continuous-integration, devops, continuous-deployment

I have a project that has a Next.js/React frontend and python/postgresql backend. Currently, I have setup a Github actions that runs playwright tests that tests a frontend feature branch with the deployed live backend (master). However, I'm not sure if this is best practice and if not, should I be creating a frontend and backend in the Github actions before running the tests? Also, would it be better (if even possible) to run docker compose in a Github action and then execute playwright tests? How would one approach automating end to end testing?